# How do I read the query in a mongoose callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My code runs through a .forEach() loop over an array. Each iteration runs a mongoose query.

My query is returning an empty object, which shouldn't happen, and I want to know why!

I can't ask the callback to print the value used, as the forEach loop has completed by the time the promise resolves, so it just prints the last item of the array (which is the expected result).

How can I access the query that was run in a mongoose callback?

```
array.forEach((item,i)=>{
    model.findOneAndUpdate({a:item.a},item).exec((err,result)=>{
        if(err){throw(err.stack);return;}

        if(!result)
            throw new Error("Nothing returned for query: "+QUERY_STRING)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from this:

```
array.forEach((item,i)=>{
    model.findOneAndUpdate({a:item.a},item).exec((err,result)=>{
        if(err){throw(err.stack);return;}

        if(!result)
            throw new Error("Nothing returned for query: "+QUERY_STRING)
    })
})
```

To this:

```
array.forEach((item,i)=>{
    (function (item, i) {
        model.findOneAndUpdate({a:item.a},item).exec((err,result)=>{
            if(err){throw(err.stack);return;}
            console.log(item, i);
            if(!result)
                throw new Error("Nothing returned for query: "+QUERY_STRING)
        })
    })(item, i)
})
```

Comment: This makes so much sense. I'm still wrapping my head around the javascript concept of "anything can be a function".